# MySQL: ORDER BY produces wrong order using long string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, mysql-5.7

I have a table with `VARCHAR(255)` column that carries the following strings.

```
1
2
5
22
text
```

I need to normalize the strings and sort them like that. I prefix them with `0`, so that I get the following information while ordering:

```
0001
0002
0005
0022
text
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT right(concat('000000000000000000000000000000000000', test), 36)
FROM my_table
ORDER BY right(concat('000000000000000000000000000000000000', test), 36);
```

If `number_of_chars` in `right()` call is small enough (say 16) the order is correct, but if I use 36 the order is incorrect: string `5` comes before `2`.

```
000000000000000000000000000000000005
000000000000000000000000000000000002
```

**Question:** What is the reason of such behaviour? Is it a bug? How to fix it?

Here is what my table looks like:

```
mysql> describe my_table;
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                         | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| test                       | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.15

Comment: Will left padding the non-numeric strings really do what you want?

Comment: normalize the strings - eh?

Comment: This is highly reproducible.  It is as if sorting doesn't work:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/31709.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, `test` -> `0000test` is what I expect.

Comment: @Strawberry maybe it is not the best word, all I want is to prefix all strings with zero so that they all will have the same length.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that after 21 char the right sub-string with string padding don't work .. but 
you can use simply [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)  this work also for 100  or more

```
SELECT test
FROM my_table
ORDER BY lpad(test,100, '0')
```

Comment: @OleksandrShpota I have test and the same happen to me  .. strange  .. could be that for the order by of substr there are some limitation of could be a bugs  .. .. but for limitation i have not found any ref in mysql doc

Answer (score 0):

This is highly reproducible and quite curious.  For instance, this produces an incorrect ordering:

```
SELECT right(concat(repeat('0', 36), test), 36) as val
FROM (select 'abcd' as test union all
      select '5' as test union all
      select '2' as test union all
      select '13' as test union all
      select '10013' as test union all
      select 'def' as test
     ) t
ORDER BY val ;
```

Interestingly, adding `DESC` seems to fix the problem, but `ASC` doesn't.

Normally, in this circumstance, you want the numbers first followed by all the text.  Your version will intersperse the non-numbers with the numbers of the same length.

I recommend doing this with separate expressions:

```
ORDER BY (left(test, 1) between '0' and '9') desc,
         test + 0,
         test
```

This sorting does appear to work.

Comment: @scaisEdge . . . In my example, it fails at 11 (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/31728).

Answer (score -1):

You are using **strings** in order by so it won't consider numbers n string differently. For example 
U have 11,12,01,03,
You will get

01
11
12
03 like this only

Comment: No, it won’t. It uses lexicographical ordering which means that 03 will come before 11 and 12 as 0 goes before 1.

Comment: yep, Sasha is right. if you sort without '0' you will get results as you show